# Passing a javascript variable to php and then back to html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html page with a form where I'd like to submit a value and send it, using javascript (w/jquery & ajax), to a php page where a certain process occurs, which I'd like to keep track of on the html page by sending back a variable multiple times to the original html page, perhaps into the empty div (id=txtHint). Below is what I have so far...

**me.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Generator</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="howdy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="form_container">
        <h1>Generator</h1>
        <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
            <input id="myStr" type="text">
            <input id="regrForm" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </center>
        </form> 
    </div>
    <div id="txtHint"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**howdy.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#regrForm").click(function(){

        var myText = $("#myStr").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'tracker.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                newStr: myText},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data){
                console.log("It went through!");
                $('#txtHint').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**tracker.php**

```
<?php
    $myName = $_POST['newStr'];
    echo "<p> My string is: " . $myName . "</p>";

    for ($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++){

        //analyze stuff

        if ($i % 100000 === 0){
            echo "Total number of things analyzed: " . $i . " from " . $myName;
        }
    }
?>
```

The problem is, I'm not entirely sure my variables are getting passed appropriately from javascript to php and also how exactly to pass the php updates (which iteration I'm on via $i) back to the html page...any thoughts? If I'm not providing enough information, please let me know. I appreciate any constructive help you can offer.

Comment: It sounds like you want to pass back multiple HTTP responses for a single POST request, is that what you are trying to do?  Generally speaking, this kind of pattern is far more challenging to implement than a single response.  I'm not personally a PHP expert, however I suspect the code you've got isn't going to do what you want as written.  Maybe something like this might help? https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php Also (somewhat unrelated), is howdy.js supposed to be referenced in your HTML? just want to make sure we're looking at the right stuff.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I edited the js filename referenced in the html doc. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For development purposes with AJAX.

1. console.log(data) from the ajax->success() method so you can see the response output from the PHP.
2. If you want to see how it's being sent just var_dump($_POST);
3. View your web-server error log file if you using APACHE/Linux it will be in your /var/log/httpd/error_log run this cmd in linux so you can't view the errors ----  tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log

Looking at your PHP code it looks like your going to crash the browser your running a for loop one million times... and then every 10-thousand times your printing "Total number of things analyzed..."

What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: it appears the OP is trying to have a single POST yield multiple callbacks (i.e. HTTP responses).  The sort of thing that would require sockets or long polling so you can see intermediate steps in some long-running process.

Comment: @killthrush yea I agree whatever he is trying to accomplish he should def be using a socket connection or long polling like you mentioned.

Comment: I'm definitely looking for multiple callbacks if possible. So how would I go about doing that? You mentioned sockets or long polling? Any good examples you could point me to?

Comment: I still don't quite understand what your trying to accomplish? But you really should use a web-socket if your looking for the server to push data to the client. You can read up on web-sockets here ---> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API and once you understand the technology and the mechanics of how it works, you should look at using a really well developed websocket framework called node.js ---> https://nodejs.org/

Comment: @Jordan Davis: I'm basically wanting a dynamic update of my txtHint div with a single message from the large for-loop in my tracker.php file. As it currently stands, if I update my success function to include "$('#txtHint').html(data);" this will only include a concatenated output of all the messages concatenated together after the tracker.php file gets done with the for-loops. I only want one dynamically updated message to replace my "txtHint" div on my html page. Looking at your link. Seems to be what I'm looking for: event-driven responses without having to poll the server continually...

Comment: @ADT exactly, yea long polling requires the client side to have a "timing" mechanism to execute another ajax request to poll the server based on whatever you set the timer to, not sure what type of application your making, but just think about 1,000 users all connecting and disconnecting, and trying to scale it efficiently would become a nightmare whereas if you you need "real-time" updates you should just have a solid connection (web-socket).

Comment: @ADT when your using web-sockets a user connects to the server and keeps the connection "alive", it will cost more money since your server is holding in active process for each user which will create a higher load than an ajax request, however it makes scaling the application 100x easier, and your data is in real-time! rather than a timing delay such as polling for example every 5-minutes (whatever you set the timer for) from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is are getting passed from javascript to php.
Just Update the success function to become like this

```
success: function(data)
{
    $('#txtHint').html(data);

    console.log("It went through!");
}
```

The results will be printed in "#txtHint" node.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I'm trying to get the "txtHint" div to be dynamically replaced with the echo from the tracker.php file, so that I will see an update on my html page as I go through the whatever I am analyzing in that loop. For example, I want to see a continuously updated message that tells me: "Total number of things analyzed: 200000 from [text entered into textbox]". If I update my code as you have indicated, I will see multiple messages all concatenated together and then printed into the #txtHint div after it's all complete. Any suggestions on how to get the dynamic update?

Comment: Since you are dealing with http request in your example, It will not achieve what you want because the response will not come back till the page finishes processing. You cannot get multiple responses for one request. You can apply multiple requests; one for each loop (**NOT RECOMMENDED**) . To get realtime updates I suggest you use [socket.io](http://socket.io).

Answer (score -1):

A few things to note:

- You have a `</center>` that should not be there in html
- I'm not sure about `dataType: "text"`, try removing that
- To see the php data in html

  instead of

  ```
  console.log("It went through!");
  ```

  do this

  ```
  $('#txtHint').html(data);
  ```